# Suction Plates in Wind Tunnels

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, aerodynamics

Let us think of a wind tunnel designed for race car applications. Suction plates plates are used to control the boundary layer and they can be placed upstream the car or under the car as well.
I find it logical to place the suction plate upstream the car and here is my explanation. If we think of a car moving through air with no winds (freestream velocity is zero), we can't expect a boundary layer to be formed. Similary in a wind tunnel, there shouldn't be a boundary layer formed by the ground upstream the car and therefore suction plates are used.
However I can't quite understand the idea of placing a suction plate underneath the car. Air under the car is under the effect of the car and using a suction plate under the car can make the test results diverge from the actual results. I know this logic is wrong and indeed most large wind tunnels have suction plates under the car. What's the reason behind this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some experience with wind tunnel testing, but I've never seen any suction plate under the car.

### Wind tunnel setup for race car

The typical setup is:

- car placed on a rolling belt, so that wheels can spin
- suction section just before the leading edge of the belt, in order to remove the boundary layer created in the wind tunnel (while this doesn't exist in real life). If you remove the boundary layer before the belt, and the belt motion is consistent with the wind speed you don't need suction on the belt to remove boundary layer, because (ideally) no extra boundary layer is formed on the belt, since (always ideally) there is no relative speed between the wind and the belt.

In this setup, it's already very hard to tune this apparatus, including belt motion and tension (to avoid oscillation and undesired vibration). But when everything is properly tuned, you don't need to add suction from the belt (and the extra complications to the experimental setup that it carries with it).

Katz (1st edition, p.76) talks about an extra suction below the rolling belt. This could be a way to control the belt behavior, and avoid that it can be sucked towards the floor of the car, due to the ground effect. Belt is not infinitely rigid, it's deformable. In order to avoid undesired deformation of the belt (since you want to replicate some meaningful condition, and real cars don't attract the concrete of the street towards their floor), you need to apply tensile solicitations; if tensile solicitations is not enough, as an example for race car with strong ground effect, you try to lower the pressure below the belt in order to avoid deformation due to large pressure difference on the two sides of the belt (the one looking at the floor of the car, experiencing low pressure due to ground effect, and the one looking under the floor of the wind tunnel, that would experience approximately ambient pressure, without any control)

### Cheaper wind tunnel setup

Extra suction under the car is used whenever you don't have a rolling belt in your wind tunnel facility, to keep sucking fictitious boundary layer created in the wind tunnel.
As described by Katz, you can have an alternative solution: instead of sucking boundary layer, you can blow "new air" to push the slow air of the boundary layer.

*Anyway, in this facility, you need a roller under each wheel to make them spin, since you'd better perform experiments with wheel rotation*.

If you add some references describing the apparatus with suction under the floor of the car, I'll take a look and further edit this answer, if needed.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I didn't think of the possible speed difference between the belt and wind which may indeed be the reason. Here is the reference of the book I am reading : 'Race Car Aerodynamics-Designing for Speed by Joseph Katz 1st Edition' (Page 73-76).

Comment: I took a look at the book, and edited my previous answer. Let me know if it's clear now.

Comment: It's definitely clear this time, much appreciated.

Comment: Perfect. Please accept the answer, so that the community can see that there is a decent answer to the question. See you next time, if you have any doubts about fluid dynamics, I'll try to give you some clarifications, if I can